# ASP.NET Core Razor using property as base for post form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

```
@model Tuple<ApplicationsModel, AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties>>

<div style="padding: 20px">
    <form method="post" action="/TDShop/AddNewProduct">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.ID);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Rel);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.CatalogueID);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Name);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Thumbnail);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.SubGroupID);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Unit);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Active);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.VAT);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.DisplayIndex);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.ShortDescription);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.LongDescription);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Sale);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Keywords);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Price);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.PurchasePrice);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Tag.Klasifikacija);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Tag.TransportnoPakovanje);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Tag.TransportnoPakovanjeJM);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Tag.KupovinaSamoUTransportnomPakovanju);
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Item2.Tag.PovezaniProizvod);
        <button>Create</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, i am sending `Tuple<ApplicationsModel, AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties>>` as my model but for my form i use only `Item2`. Problem is my `inputs` are named `Item2.ID, Item2.Rel etc.` and when i try to catch my object inside post with this: `public IActionResult AddNewProduct(AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties> product)` it is not valid, but if that first part `Item2` is removed, then it would work.

Is there a way to remove it inside razor?

**EDIT**
I have tried adding this:

```
@{ 
    AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties> p = Mode.item2;
}
```

and using it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => p.ID)
```

but it names it `p.ID` instead of `ID`

Answer (score 2):

Found solution and discovered one more brilliant thing.

First of all my own answer from edit worked but all i needed to do was change my `HttpPost` method from `AddNewProduct(AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties> product` to `AddNewProduct(AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties> p` (same as i called it inside my View.

What i discovered is instead of calling each property like this all i had to do is call it like `@Html.EditorFor(x => pr)` and it would list all properties!

So my full working code now looks like this:

```
@model Tuple<ApplicationsModel, AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties>>
@AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties> p = Model.Item2;

<div style="padding: 20px">
    <form method="post" action="/TDShop/AddNewProduct">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => p)
        <button>Create</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and catching it with `AddNewProduct(AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties> p`

> So clean :')